# jQuery UI sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a ul, kinda like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
   <li data-name="name1">
   <li data-name="name2">
   <li data-name="name3">
</ul>
```

I am using jQuery sortable and i need to know, when there is a sort change, what is the order of the lis. I am using:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({ 
        axis: 'y',
        stop: function(evt, ui){
            console.log($("#sortable").sortable('toArray'));
        }
    });
```

the problem with "toArray" is that it relies only on the unique ids of the items and i can't use that attribute on those lis, for reasons.

Is there any way to make toArray, return an array with the data-attribute data-name instead of the id?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$("#sortable").sortable('toArray', { attribute: 'data-name' })
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sSkPx/)

Comment: +1 Was just about to write the same after viewing [the source here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js)

Comment: @ManseUK Same here. Not actually sure this works, but saw the options parameter that gets passed into [the method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js#L423). I'm assuming passing an object as the second argument will end up as `toArray()`'s argument.